# Difference between () and [] in Perl 6

Tags: raku

**Note**  This SO should not have the raku tag. It is too obsolete/misleading. The technical problem discussed in the question body no longer applies. The disagreement in the comments about naming/tags no longer applies. I'm leaving it for historical interest only, under the old tag only.

---

I am learning Perl 6, and had trouble understanding the Perl 6 one-liner below

My Perl 6  is `rakudo-star: stable 2014.04 (bottled)`

This works fine. The array/list is sorted

```
[njia@mb-125:~] : perl6 -e 'say [2443,5,33, 90, -9, 2, 764].sort'
-9 2 5 33 90 764 2443
```

But this does not sort the array/list, if `[].sort` works why `@s.sort` does not?

```
[njia@mb-125:~] : perl6 -e 'my @s = [2443,5,33, 90, -9, 2, 764]; @s.sort.say'
2443 5 33 90 -9 2 764
```

Change from `[]` to `()`

```
[njia@mb-125:~] : perl6 -e 'my @s = (2443,5,33,90,-9,2,764); @s.sort.say'
-9 2 5 33 90 764 2443
```

---

> **NOTE** the described behavior in this question has changed in the release version of perl6. See response by [G. Cito](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24328496/2019415) below.

Comment: @FranciscoZarabozo: Perl 6 *is* Perl; it just isn't Perl 5

Comment: Perl6 and Perl are different tags. From a language perspective, Perl 5 and Perl 6 are completely different languages. My edit focused on removing the `perl` tag and keep only `perl6`. People looking for the `perl` tag are most likely not looking for Perl 6. For tagging purposes, `perl` is not `perl6` and `perl` is an unrelated tag.

Comment: @FranciscoZarabozo:

I really don't want this to turn into a battle of egos so I will leave you to fiddle with the tags to your heart's content, but I disagree strongly with *"Perl 5 and Perl 6 are completely different"*.

Perl 6 is far more like Perl 5 than any other language, but because Perl 6 staked its claim early to the major version number, Perl 5 was forced to keep incrementing the minor version number. So versions 10 and 20 of Perl 5 have become what would have been Perl 6 and Perl 7 if it wasn't for the roadblock.

Comment: It is only because of my understanding of Perl in general that I could swiftly answer this question about Perl 6. The answer would have been similarly clear to someone who knew only Perl 4.

I can agree that those who have an opinion on the matter must be educated, whether they be Perl users or otherwise, and that Stack Overflow's wiki for relevant tags should be reassessed. But I don't believe that tags should be adjusted in the light of popular misconceptions. Before long we would be tagging `ECMAScript` questions with `Java`, *"just in case"*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For those who may be confused by this answer, the question is about ***Perl 6***, and none of this applies to Perl 5.

The statement

```
my @s = [2443, 5, 33, 90, -9, 2, 764]
```

creates an itemised array and assigns it to `@s[0]`, so `@s` has only a single element and sorting it is pointless.

However you *can* say

```
@s[0].sort.say
```

which has the effect you expected

Comment: A succint explanation +1. In perl6 the difference between a list and array was made more explicit and in some ways more "consistent" (*i.e.* assignment to a scalar does not return the number of items of a list as in perl5). This perl6 feature helped me to appreciate the subtle and idiom building power of lists versus arrays in perl5.

Comment: @Borodin [@Ask and Learn](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2681383/ask-and-learn) ... it's been 4+ years but as of the Xmas release of perl6 this has changed. Possibly due to reworking things during Great List Refactor.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to go out on a limb and refer to some of CPAN's Perl6 documentation where this could be viewed as a [list vs. array thing](http://search.cpan.org/~lichtkind/Perl6-Doc/lib/Perl6/Doc/Overview/Data.pod#Lists_vs._Arrays) - *i.e.* a [sequence of values](http://doc.perl6.org/type/Array) versus a [sequence of itemized values](http://doc.perl6.org/type/Array) (see `doc.perl6.org`).

Certainly perl6 is different enough that it warrants its own tag but **it is still** `perl` so it's not surprising that `()` creates a list and `[]` creates an anonymous array.

```
> say [2443, 5, 33, 90, -9, 2, 764].WHAT
(Array)
> say (2443, 5, 33, 90, -9, 2, 764).WHAT
(List)
```

Since this question was first asked and answered the behavior has changed:

```
> my @s = [2443, 5, 33, 90, -9, 2, 764]
> @s.sort.say
(-9 2 5 33 90 764 2443)
```

Note that the output when sorted is a `List` but otherwise `@s` is an `Array`:

```
> @s.sort.WHAT.say
(List)
> @s.WHAT.say
(Array)
```

Comment: As of Rakudo 2023.05, the Raku (a.k.a. Perl6) code examples in this post are correct when run in the Raku REPL, with one (minor) exception. The exception is that `@s.sort.WHAT.say` now returns a `(Seq)`, which is a lightweight _"iterable, potentially lazy sequence of values"_ in Raku. Of course, to get a list back you simply add `.List` to the method-chain.